# Get all UNIQUEIDENTIFIER values based on variables in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Goal is to get all `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` values from all columns in database.

Code which is supposed to load all those values:

```
DECLARE @TableNames TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0, 1),
    TableName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ColName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @Guids TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0, 1),
    FoundGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
);    

DECLARE @Local NVARCHAR(50);
WHILE @Counter < 500
BEGIN
    SELECT @Local = TableName FROM @TableNames WHERE Id = @Counter;
    INSERT INTO @Guids EXEC('SELECT Id FROM [' + @Local + ']');
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END;
```

Is this safe thing to do so? Eventually, what is the way to get those values?

Comment: What do you mean you are not allowed? Did you get an error or what?

Comment: The scope of the `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` are different than you current query so you won't have access to `@Guids`, in your case you should use temp tables (e.g. `#Guids`) in the `EXEC` query.

Comment: You can't use dynamic sql in a function. use a stored procedure

Comment: I would ask why? Seems a very strange task to need to get all guid values from all tables. What could you possibly be trying to accomplish with that? If it just an exercise I would suggest you look at sys.columns and sys.tables to find all the columns with the datatype you are looking for. Then it also doesn't have to be the column named Id.

Comment: the table variable `@Guids` is not out of scope. The query by itself should be fine. But if you are implementing this inside a function, that will not work as function does not allow dynamic sql

Comment: @Squirrel So am I supposed to rewrite it into a procedure?

Comment: yes. Function does not allow `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: I would do the whole thing in a single go. Instead of creating and populating a table variable. You can leverage sys.tables and sys.columns to build your dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the system views to generate dynamic sql. This is 100% accurate and not limited to only those columns named Id. It won't matter what schema or column name is used. This will get you all those values with no looping at all.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
    + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    + ' UNION ALL '
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.types ty on ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where ty.name = 'uniqueidentifier'

--removes the last UNION ALL
select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL

--uncomment below to execute the dynamic sql when you are comfortable it is correct
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```